# Can't import scss variables from another file in Next.js

Tags: next.js, sass

I have a `globals.scss` file that have global styles like text colors and stuff. I have another file called `variables.scss` that I want to import variables from like so. This is in Next.js.

```scss
@import url("../styles/variables.scss");

html,
body {
  background-color: variables.$background;
  color: variables.$foreground;
}
```

I also tried

```scss
@use "../styles/variables.scss";
```

But it doesn't work

The directory structure is like like this

```
src
- app
  - globals.scss
- styles
  - variables.scss
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I imported the variables file wrong.

It should be

```scss
@import "../styles/variables";
```

And there shouldn't be `variables.` in front of of each variable